# Simplest database implementation

Tags: database, nosql

I am looking for a really simple database implementation; basically one with no complex parsing SQL engine. What I am looking for is something demonstrating B+ trees and ACID storage (Suitable for educational purposes). What I have found up-till now form my current searches was hamster-db. I am looking for something even simpler with a smaller code-base. If there is any such opensource project in your knowledge please let me know.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The University of Wisconsin Databases group uses their own small relational database, [minirel](http://www.cs.wisc.edu/coral/minibase/logMgr/report/node3.html), to teach the undergraduate databases class. I just took it, actually; it's enlightening. My semester's assignments are [posted publicly](http://pages.cs.wisc.edu/~cs564-2/projects.html). I'm sure the faculty would be willing to part with the source code used at each step.

In the undergraduate class, we do not implement B+ trees or ACID components, but it appears that the larger project does include them.

Answer (score -1):

You can try to look at [OrientDB](http://code.google.com/p/orient/). Don't know if it's simpler than hamster-db, but it's open source, uses a mix of Red-Black Tree and B+Tree algorithms and [supports](http://www.orientechnologies.com/orient-db.htm) ACID.